# How do I get my navigation menu to adjust with my div

Tags: html, css, navbar

I was just wondering how do I get my navigation menu to adjust in width as my div box does? help would be great!

Here is the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/AtM2Q/

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 9pt;
}
ul#navmenu li {
min-width: 203px;
max-width: 285px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
margin-right: 0px;
display:inline-block;
}
   #navmenu ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
white-space:nowrap;
}
#page1 {
text-align: center;
}
ul#navmenu a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width: 100%;
min-width: 203px;
max-width: 285px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 25px;
background-color: #2E2E2E;
border: 1px solid #777777;
border-top: 2px solid #777777;
color: white;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-face: Arial;
float: left;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;

}
ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
margin-top: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
margin-left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
background-color: grey;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
background-color: red;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 126px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
display: block;
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
display: block;
}
.darrow {
font-size: 8pt;
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
right: 1px;
    }
    #navmenu {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;

    }
    .rarrow {
font-size: 8pt;
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 0px;
    }
    ul#navmenu {
width:100% !important;
    }
    #page1 .link1 {
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
    }
    #page2 .link2 {
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
    }
    #page3 .link3 {
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
    }
    .container {
width: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
max-width: 1440px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;


}
#box2 {
height: 1000px;
 width: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
max-width: 1440px;
height: 1000px;
background-color: yellow;
float: left;
margin: 0px auto;
}
#boxinbox1 {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: #E51837;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#E51837">

    <div id="box2">
        <div id="page1">
            <div id="boxinbox1">weiuhgqiogq</div>
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="dropdown1.html" class="link1">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="dropdown2.html" class="link2">hyperlink 2</a><font color="white">
<span class="darrow">&#9660;</font>
                    </span>
                    <ul class="sub1">
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4</a><span class="darrow"><font color="white">&#9660;               

 </font></span> 
                    <ul class="sub1">
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3</a><span class="rarrow">
<font color="white">&#9654;</font></span>

                            <ul class="sub2">
                                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
<a href="dropdown3.html" class="link3">hyperlink 4.3.3</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

__________________________________________________________________________oamgogeponrbapoenbepoanbaepobneaporibnmaeorpbinmepobaeponbaepornbwponbwrpoBNWpornbwropUNBWORPBWPOrbwoprBWOI[rbjw[J[owigjw[oiGJWr[ogj[worgijw[rPGJ

Comment: your html is a mess. lots of unclosed tags and also the <font> tag is deprecated: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
    ul#navmenu a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width: 50%;   
max-width: 285px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 25px;
background-color: #2E2E2E;
border: 1px solid #777777;
border-top: 2px solid #777777;
color: white;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-face: Arial;
float: left;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;

}
```

remove min-width its not necessary and give width size to 50%, you have given it has 100%, it was covering all over the div
along with that

```
     ul#navmenu li {
border:1px solid white;
max-width: 285px;
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
margin-right: 0px;
display:inline-block;
 }
```

this is the css which is used to give width and border to "li" apply this you will be able to see what you looking for, i did it on your fiddle it worked fine

[image]

let me know

Comment: hi thanks for the help just wondering why there is white and emptiness where hyperlinks should be?

Comment: I have given for your information so that we can increase the width and border for that menu, you can decrease the width of ul#navmenu li and remove border:1px solid white, will gives your answer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly...
You have to set the width of the ul#navmenu li in %.

With 5 main-navigation points like you have it at the moment..
Do stuff like:

```
ul#navmenu li {
    width: 19%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

But I'll recommend to use Twitter-Bootstrap...

Comment: is's a front-end framework, it make it easy to create good-looking "normal" and mobile websites. (more infos hear http://getbootstrap.com/)